# Random access to array of raw buffers of different sizes?

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, random-access

I have an array of array: `struct chunk { char * data; size_t size; }; chunk * chunks;`. The data size in each chunk is dynamic and differ between chunks. Linear access to data is easy with a nested for loop:

```
for (chunk * chunk_it = chunks; chunk_it != chunks + count; ++chunk_it) {
    for (char * it = chunk_it->data; it != chunk_it->data + chunk_it->size; ++it) {
        /* use it here */
    }
}
```

I want to turn this into random access to `chunks->data` using `operator[]` as an interface, spanning **multiple chunks**.

It works by linearly searching for the right chunk, then just calculating the offset of the data I want.

```
template <class T>
void random_access(int n) {
    chunk * c;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        c = chunks + i;
        size_t size = c->size;
        if (n - size < 0) {
            n -= size; // mutate n to fit into current chunk
        } else {
            break; // found
        }
    }

    T * data = reinterpret_cast<T *>(c->data + n);

    // use data here
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? It would be crazy to do this every time I need a T from chunks. I plan on iterating over all chunk data linearly, but I want to use the data outside of the function, and thus need to return it at the inner loop (hence why I want to turn it inside out). I also thought of using a function pointer at the inner loop, but rather not as just doing `chunk_iterator[n]` is much nicer.

Comment: *C++ arrays* are meant to be [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)... You are not using *C* here...

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use `std::vector<std::string> chunks`?

Comment: Whenever you will call `random_access()`, it is prone to say "**Cannot resolve identifier *c***"... The variable `chunk * c` is inside the loop, how will that even compile!

Comment: They are all dummy types and greatly simplified code. ```chunks::data``` is a raw byte buffer. I'm aware that type safety is thrown out the window. As for choosing vector, the chunks themselves are different types. So a std::tuple<type1, type2, type N> might have worked if they were possible to do dynamically, and not a nightmare to iterate over.

Comment: You could make a contiguous block of all your chunks and store pointers to the individual chunks in your `chunks` array.

Comment: How can you iterate over chunks using pointer arithmetic if your chunk objects are of different types? In fact how can you have an array of them?

Comment: Use a tree? (you can use std::set::lower_bound to avoid implementing your own)

Comment: @Galik the actual data is stored in 16KB contiguous raw blocks of memory. I stored some meta data of what abstract types and individual type-size they may contain in the very beginning of each block (they are in fact components of a very low level ECS system). Traversing the blocks from a to z is no biggie, until I needed to search for only particular blocks matching a criteria, and traverse them with random access. Your answer is very elegant so I'll give it a serious shot at converting to standard types (vector) as per your suggestion. Greatly appreciated! This low level business is hard :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your data structure is more complicated but could you not do something like this?

I build a contiguous block of the *chunk data* and record the *position* and *size* of each one in the *chunks array*:

```
class chunk_manager
{
    struct chunk
    {
        std::size_t position;
        std::size_t size;

        chunk(std::size_t position, std::size_t size)
        : position(position), size(size) {}
    };

public:

    void add_chunk(std::string const& chunk)
    {
        m_chunks.emplace_back(m_data.size(), chunk.size());
        m_data.append(chunk);
    }

    char* random_access(std::size_t n) { return &m_data[n]; }

    std::size_t size_in_bytes() const { return m_data.size(); }

private:
    std::vector<chunk> m_chunks;
    std::string m_data;
};

int main()
{
    chunk_manager cm;

    cm.add_chunk("abc");
    cm.add_chunk("def");
    cm.add_chunk("ghi");

    for(auto n = 0ULL; n < cm.size_in_bytes(); ++n)
        std::cout << cm.random_access(n) << '\n';
}
```